# How can I convert this C# 2 delegate example to C# 3 lambda syntax?

Tags: c#, lambda

---

I've got this example where I convert a **C# 2** delegate example:

```
Predicate<string> predicate2 = delegate(string n)
{
    return n.StartsWith("J");
};
IList<string> namesWithJ2 = Tools.Filter(names, predicate2);
Tools.Dump(namesWithJ2);
```

to **C# 3** lambda syntax example:

```
var filteredNames = Tools.Filter(names, n => n.StartsWith("J"));
Tools.Dump(filteredNames);
```

---

But how to I convert this to lambda syntax? Particularly, how do I get the **two parameters** (object s, DoWorkEventArgs args) to be passed using the "=>"?

```
_worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = s as BackgroundWorker;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            args.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        worker.ReportProgress(i + 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: Lambdas should be used as expressions, cos it compiles into expression tree, and there i see no advantages of using lambda. Why wont you leave it as anonymous method?

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with Yossarian. I think lambdas should be used for expressions because they make the code more readable. But for my money, lambdas which require curly brackets DON'T make the code more readable, and I'd say it's a code smell.

Comment: Banjol, So you agree with me :) (to make it clear: this is imo misuse of lambdas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outline of the form is

```
_worker.DoWork += (s, args) => {body of method};
```

Other punctuation as the compiler advises

Answer (score 1):

```
_worker.DoWork += (s, args) => {
    ....
};
```

Or if the compiler can't figure out the exact types of s and args:

```
_worker.DoWork += (object s, DoWorkEventArgs args) => {
    ....
};
```